# Run specific instrumentation test suite with Gradle Managed Devices - Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, android-studio-dolphin

So with the release of Android Studio Dolphin & Beta of Electric Eel, I wanted to try the instrumentation tests in gradle. I do however want to exclude some of the tests being run, in order to be able to run specific test suites one at a time.

So here is what I configured so far:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    managedDevices {
      devices {
        pixel2api30 (com.android.build.api.dsl.ManagedVirtualDevice) {
          device = "Pixel 2"
          apiLevel = 30
          systemImageSource = "aosp-atd"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know I can run my entire suite using

```
./gradlew device-nameBuildVariantAndroidTest
```

In my case that would be

```
./gradlew pixel2api30gaeDebugAndroidTest
```

gaeDebug being my build variant. This command is being run in my project root.

If I want to run the tests in the tests/large folder for example

[image: File structure]

How would I go about doing that? Thanks.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but how did you set the different icons for different packages?

Comment: @TWiStErRob Atom icons plugin

Answer (score 1):

For this you could use 2 different approaches:

1. Create and run test suites.

For example, for each of these folders, create a `TestSuite` and define Test classes. For example:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    ExampleLargeTest.class,
    ExampleTwoLargeTest.class,
    ExampleThreeLargeTest.class
})
public class LargeTestsSuite {
}
```

This suite can be run using following command

```
./gradlew pixel2api30gaeDebugAndroidTest - Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=path.to.your.suite.class
```

2. Use Test Categories

Annotate your Test classes like this:

```
@Category("Large")
public class ExampleLargeTest { ... }
```

And then you could execute the following command for running all tests with same category:

```
    ./gradlew pixel2api30gaeDebugAndroidTest -PtestCategory=Large
```

Hopefully one of these two approaches will suite you.